# Accessing UISegmentedcontrol selectedIndex - when contained in a UIButton contained in the UINavigationController.toolbar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am currently adding a `UISegmentedControl` to the toolbar in the navigation controller programmatically (as seen below).

This approach works fine, I have my `UISegmentedControl`, it fires the selector that I have setup no problems.

Problem is - I would like to use the `selectedIndex` of this control in order to query my data model and present a different view of data for each 'segment' - but I am having trouble getting the `selectedIndex`.

In my travels I have been consulting the 'Top Songs' example code provided by Apple.
In this code they build up their interface via `UISegmentedControl` object in the view controller and IB.  In doing so they can access the `UISegmentedControl`'s `selectedIndex`.  I am adding mine programmactically and do not have this freedom.

'SHOULD' I have a `UISegmentedControl` defined in my view controller? If so, if I want to continue building my menu programmactically, how do I go about accessing the information from the control buried within the navigation controller's `UIToolBar`?

I'm clearly missing something basic.  Any assistance is always greatly appreciated :)

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

// Set up the edit and add buttons.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];

NSArray *tabitems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ONE", @"TWO", @"THREE", @"FOUR", nil];
UISegmentedControl *tabs = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:tabitems];

[tabs addTarget:self
    action:@selector(pickedSegment:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

tabs.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
tabs.frame = CGRectMake(60, 8, 180, 30);
tabs.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
//[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:tabs];
[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:tabs];
[tabs release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `tabs` defined in your .h file -

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
    ....
    UISementedControl *tabs;
    ....
@end
....
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *tabs;
```

Then, after the `[tabs release];` line, you should still be able to access the object, as it is a retained property - access the `selectedItemIndex` as normal.

Comment: In addition, @Lance should use `self.tabs = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:tabitems];` (important not to forget the "self." - otherwise it won't use the property setter and won't retain the instance...).

Comment: Many thanks to all!! I figured out the self.tabs business on my travels but thanks for the update!

Comment: Can you mark as answer please the if it was the answer? Many thanks

Comment: How do I go about that sorry?

Comment: Below the reputation increase/decrease buttons, there is a hollow tick. If you click it, it goes green, and shows that you have accepted my answer as the answer to your question. It gives me +15 rep and you +2.

Comment: For anyone trying to plug together the idea of a UISegmentedControl in the NavigationController.toolbar, the code quoted above is performed in the viewDidLoad();